# Why don't we make a bracha on bentching?

Tags: blessing, bentching

Bircas Hamazon is a mitzva from the Torah, so why don't we make a bracha on this mitzva?

Comment: Before putting on Tefillin I fulfill the mitzva of saying the blessing להניח תפילין. Why don't I say a blessing on that mitzva?

Comment: @DoubleAA Birkas hamazon is different than tefillin. tefillin is the main mitzvah; rabbanon added on a bracha beforehand. They wouldn't enact to make a bracha before their own bracha. But I can understand the OP- since birkas hamazon is a torah mitzvah, the rabbonim should have made a bracha on it. Similar to birkas cohanim, where we make a bracha before making the bracha (though obviously there are differences between the cases).

Comment: Ive seen from somewhere.. i think shalal rav on pesach. On 4 cups.. that we don't make a bracha on a bracha.

Comment: Good question, but don't see why it's relevant that the mitzvah is *min hatorah*. Mitzvos of rabbinic origin also have *birchas hamitzvos*

Comment: Some hold that one doesn't make a *bracha* on something which is primarily performed by inner thoughts - *davar hatoluy belev* - (such as *bittul chametz*; see Kol Bo #48; or *sefiras zavah*; see Teshuvas R' Akiva Eiger 29), even when they must be expressed verbally. Perhaps *birchas hamazon* which is an expression of gratitude can be considered so?

Comment: @Binyomin The analogue to tefillin is eating, not bentching.

Comment: @DoubleAA There is no mitzva to eat.

Comment: @chortkov2 Yeah to be more correct one of the 620 commandments. (I can't think of a bracha made on anything else) The majority of those are min hatorah though.

Comment: @chortkov2 Yeah but one does not fulfill one's obligation just by thinking. We make a bracha on Torah and Shema.

Comment: @user6781 at least for certain construals of that word, sure, but so what? It's clearly ridiculous to add a blessing on a blessing on an action אין לדבר סוף

Comment: @binyomin one can say that birkas Kohanim is not something that is derived from logic since HaShem appointed them to be the messengers of blessing ,so fits with the answer I provide (I think).

Comment: @DoubleAA These are two different types of blessing though: birkas hamazon is blessing hashem for food, and a bracha is blessing hashem for the opportunity for the  I do think you have a point, but have you seen this savara anywheremitzvah itself, which exists by bircas hamazon equally.

Comment: @DoubleAA  I do think you have a point, but have you seen this savara anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

I have found the מעשה נסים to the Hagadah who writes about why we don't make a bracha on the mitzva of recounting the Exodus of Egypt and includes a reason why there is no bracha on bircas hamazon:

ומה שנראה לתת טעם במה שלא תקנו ברכה כי עינינו הרואות שבכל דבר שתקנו ברכה בגוף המצות לא תקנו ברכה על צוותו העשיות המצות כי אינו בדין לתקן ברכה על ברכה **דהא ברכת המזון ג"כ מצות עשה דאורייתא הוא ולא תקנו לברך אקבמו"צ לברך על המזון אלא ודאי מטעם שכתבתי כיון שמברכין השי"ת בגוף המצוה אינו בדין לתקן ברכה על ברכה** ומטעם זה לא תקנו ג"כ כאן כיון שכבר תקנו ברכה אגוף הגאולה והוא ברכת אשר גאלנו לא תקנו עוד ברכה אחרת על זה.

(Free Translation)

What seems to be a reason why they did not make a bracha [for the mitzva of recounting the Exodus of Egypt] is because our eyes see that everything that has a bracha in the actual mitzva they did not make a bracha on the commanding of the mitzva. It does not make sense to make a bracha for another bracha. Like we see by **bircas hamazon which is positive commandment and there is no bracha beforehand. Rather it must that since we are blessing hashem in the actual mitzva it does not make sense to make a bracha for another bracha.** Because of this reason they also did not make a bracha here [the recounting of the redemption], since there is already a bracha in the actual mitzva, the bracha asher goalnu, they did not institute another bracha beforehand.

Good catch, Double AA.

Answer (score 0):

A possible answer can be that a mitzvah that can be derived from common sense does not receive a bracha. When HaShem provides for a person it is logical that one thank the one who has sustained them . This idea comes from the Kad Hakemach (Tiztzis).

Text:

והוא שרז"ל חכמי האמת תקנו לנו לברך עליהן אשר קדשנו במצותיו וצונו, ועל המצות המקובלות האלה נקראו ישראל בסיני גוי קדוש שנא' (שמות י״ט:ו׳) ואתם תהיו לי ממלכת כהנים וגוי קדוש. כי בקיום המושכלות לא יקרא העם גוי קדוש כי גם העכו"ם שהם גוי אובד עצות ואין בהם תבונה הלא הם מתעסקים בקצת המצות המושכלות וגם החכמים לא תקנו לברך על המושכלות כלל כי אין עיקר הברכה והקדושה אלא במצות המקובלות, ומכלל המצות המקובלות היא מצות ציצית ומרוב הפלגת עלויה אמרו רבותינו ז"ל שהיא שקולה כנגד כל המצות

Comment: Seemingly the mitzvah of maakeh is considered a "logical mitzvah" and we nonetheless say a bracha

Comment: Not according to the Chinuch,which seems one needs to put up the Maakeh himself davka

Comment: I am unsure if bircas hamazon fits this category. I feel like bemtching adds to our גוי קדוש

Comment: This logic would make non jews obligated to bench.